# howto increase the range of WLAN - it must be a software issue - with stock firmware it was better

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, tomato, range

I own a     Netgear R7000 router. After installing Advanced Tomato firmware, the range of WLAN decreased. Upstairs there is weak connectivity.

Do I have some sort of misconfiguration?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The stock firmware might use different firmware blobs. It could also be using a different driver (version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set the channel width to auto (20/40 MHz). I've seen some devices unhappy with the 40 MHz setting.

Bigger channel width gives better speed in theory but some devices seem to be incompatible with the 40 MHz only setting. I ended up with speeds below G on a N router with this setting and back to normal N speeds with a 20/40 MHz setting.

Comment: thanks, but there is no auto option. I can only choose an integer. See https://i.imgur.com/Pqs5u4w.png

Comment: If it can't automatically choose between 20 and 40 you'll have to try 20 MHz.